# Copy a file to destination

Tags: windows, vbscript

I'm trying to create a VBS that's supposed to iterate through a directory that has folders in it, these folders have files in them. 
The folders are named after users, I want to iterate through the user folders and copy the files in them to a another folder that is also named after the user. After copying the files to the destination, it should also delete the copied files from the first folder.

This is what I currently have:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder")
Set fldrsub = fldr.SubFolders
For Each file In fldrsub
    Set firstPath = file
    myPath = Mid(firstPath,34,25)
    RTrim(myPath)
    WScript.Echo(myPath)
    Set pathTwo = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\user\Desktop\" & myPath & "\data\")
    For Each oneFile In file.Files
        WScript.Echo oneFile
        oneFile.Copy(pathTwo)   
    Next        
Next
```

It's supposed iterate through the folders, then trim the user name from the folder path, loop inside that folder and copy all the files to a destination based on the username.

I'm receiving an error "Permission Denied" (800A0046) that points to the `oneFile.Copy(pathTwo)` command, I did research on it and found that the it could be caused by a permission issue or missing a backslash on a folder destionation. After checking out my permissions and checking the folder paths I still couldn't get it to work, though.

Comment: pathtwo should be a string. `pathTwo="C:\Users\user\Desktop\" & myPath & "\data\"`.

Comment: While the default property of a folder **object** is its path, the returned **string** has no trailing backslash.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, sorry for the duplicate. I did read that other existing  question, it just didn't resolve my problem so I decided to ask the question myself, even though it was very similar.
Also got it working, thanks to the replies.